# small numbers java

Tags: java, floating-point, numbers, double, fractions

I am trying to divide two numbers in java - more specifically I have the fraction 800/9177 and want to convert it to a double or float or w/e. My problem is when I try to get the value of the fraction, I get 0.

Anybody knows how to do this?

my code:

```
double dt = 800/9177;
float ft = 800/9177;
double dw = 800/122;
System.out.println("dt : " + dt + " ft: " + ft + " dw " + dw + " 800/9177 " + (800/9177));
```

it prints dt: 0 ft: 0 dw : 6.0 800/9177 0
so all my fractions except for dw is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is

```
double dt = 800.0/9177;
```

or

```
double dt = (double) 800 / 9177;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the data type `int` will result in an `int` with loss of data. Use `double` and `float` data types from the start like this

```
double dt = 800/9177.0;
float ft = 800/9177.0f;
double dw = 800/122.0;
```

A double number rcan be specified like this

```
double d = (double) 123;
double d = 123.0; //default floating point type is double. use f for float 
double d = 123d;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double dt = 800D / 9177;
```

If you divide two ints, you get an integer division. To get a double division, one of the operands must be a double.